# Express how to use Import / require() in Static Folder

Tags: javascript, express, import

I've been trying to do this for quite some time now, does anyone know how do I use import or require in express static folder. I get require not defined and I get it its non existent in browsers and I'm too lazy to try and set up webpack/babel/browserify, is that the only way to do it and what is the fastest way?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `require` in a browser because this is CommonJS and its goal is precisely to manage modules in a non-browser environment.

The browser compliant way to manage modules is the [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) standard.

Just add the `type="module"` attribute on the `script` tags and you'll be able to use the `import` and `export` keywords in the JavaScript files.

With [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), you leverage a module management system that is native, and doesn't require a build process for the front-end JavaScript code.

If your question is about importing third party libraries, either:

- Copy them into your static folder (packaged as [ECMAScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) and add the corresponding `script` tags
- Reference them from some CDN (packaged as [ECMAScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) with `script` tags
- Use a build process to bundle/treeshake/minify the whole code, including the libraries from `node_modules`

For reference, here is a library packaged as an [ECMAScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) as well on a CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js